# How to reference system.design in a client profile project?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-client-profile

I have a project which is purely made of .net client profile.

I needed to use a control nut this control uses the reference system.design, which does not available on client profile,

I cannot change my project framework, and I need this library, so I tried to pull it and grab it as a reference dll to my project, but is did not work ..

What should I do in order to use system.design in client profile environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: you can't.

You'll have to either change the target framework or re-implement the control for the client profile.

Please see the sixth comment on [this Scott Hanselman article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TowardsASmallerNET4DetailsOnTheClientProfileAndDownloadingNET.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

*This assumes that your solution targets version 3.5 or 4.0 of the .NET Framework to be using the Client Profile.*

The Client Profile just limits the framework to allowing certain assemblies, so basically it's not possible to reference this assembly.

One thing you should notice is that with version 4.5 of the .NET Framework, Microsoft did away with the Client Profile, so looking forward, if you were to build your solution to target version 4.5 of the .NET Framework, you will only be able to use the Full Profile anyway, in which case, yes you can reference this assembly.